# The moon is 240,000 miles far away from the earth

Tags: grammaticality

The moon is 240,000 miles far away from the earth.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Your "far away" is a dictionary replacement for "distant", as in the Berkeley doctrine referred to by Warnock, mentioned by Woodger in an article called ["Proper Objects"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2251417?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) and published in Mind, Vol. 65, No. 260 (Oct., 1956), pp. 510-515. I have no idea how you came across that bit of esoterica, or if you did, but unless you understand the terms used, *substituting a term from a dictionary definition for another term is not likely to work to your advantage*.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a question that might be better answered on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

But it's a fair question: It is not incorrect, but the words "far away" are not needed. "The moon is 240,000 miles from the earth." would be the expected phrasing in native English.

Answer (score 1):

That should be:

> The Moon is 240,000 miles away from the Earth.

Answer (score 1):

I would eliminate the word *far.* *Away* is optional; *from* is essential.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers so far are correct, but one could also say, "The moon is far away: 240,000 miles from earth."